# Getting the Limit of AWS Accounts using BOTO3

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios, boto3

I need to monitor my infrastructure on AWS. For this, I am writing boto3 functions to know the limits of my account. However, I am not able to achieve the following things:

1. Limit of EBS Volumes (Not able to find any method from where I can know the max number of Volumes I can create)
2. Limit of total Number of Security Groups
3. Limit of Security rules per Security group
4. Max number of Elastic IPs. Since I have different AWS accounts and limits vary for each of these accounts. I need to take it dynamically from each account.

Comment: I doubt of this is possible. You can view the information on the dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by using trust advisor service. 
you only need to monitor the result by direct API call for Trust advisor like service limits in my case. 
https://console.aws.amazon.com/trustedadvisor/home?#/category/performance?checkId=eW7HH0l7J9

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [Trusted Advisor](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) has an API for providing limit checks. Also, specific services have API calls available to describe limits.

Take a look at [awslimitchecker](https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It seems to provide a large number of limit checks. You could even [look at the `awslimitchecker` code](https://github.com/jantman/awslimitchecker) to see how it obtains the limits.

Answer (score 1):

for #3 (getting "Inbound or outbound rules per security group"):

```
import boto3


def get_limit_value(service_code, quota_name):
    client = boto3.client('service-quotas')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_service_quotas')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(ServiceCode=service_code)
    for page in page_iterator:
        for quota in page['Quotas']:
            if quota['QuotaName'] == quota_name:
                return int(quota['Value'])

rules_per_sg = get_limit_value('vpc', 'Inbound or outbound rules per security group')
print(rules_per_sg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, AWS show you the [VPC services limit here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html)  , but some soft limit can be lifted by emailing a request to AWS.

[EBS soft limit is here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ebs).

If your real concern is the cost, then (eg.for those who host web page in AWS without CDN), you should [create a billing alarm as describe here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html).