# Is there a way to compare actual service limits for two AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

We have a standby AWS account in case we lose access to our production account. We want to make sure that service limits are exactly the same for both accounts and stay in sync. Over time various service limits have been increased for the production account.

Is there a way to list all actual service limits for an account to make them easily comparable, ideally with the AWS CLI, boto3 or whatever?

The only way I can think of is manually going through both accounts' support cases and identify limit increases like that.

Comment: Take a look at: [service-quotas — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/service-quotas/index.html)

Comment: The [Getting the Limit of AWS Accounts using BOTO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012889/getting-the-limit-of-aws-accounts-using-boto3) question might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly from CLI but https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli_usage.html may be useful to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Woopsie. My bad!